# I am facing an database rollback issues in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3

Error
Static analysis:

1 error was found during analysis.

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "LOCK" at position 58) SQL query:
>
> -- -- Dumping data for table `mgw2_inventory_stock_1` -- LOCK TABLES `mgw2_inventory_stock_1` WRITE

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1146 - Table 'pinnacle_mage476.mgw2_inventory_stock_1' doesn't exist

Please help me fix it

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because this is actually not a table.
It is a view.

So before rollback when you clear all existing tables, execute below query as well.

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS mgw2_inventory_stock_1;

This should work !!!

Comment: But its not working

Comment: Ok in my case, this resolved my issue. Just make sure query was executed. If not try with 'DROP VIEW mgw2_inventory_stock_1;' in mysql panel. Check if that works.